# Matplotlib - Plot 1D range line and scatter points on it

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, date-range, scatter

Any suggest to reproduce this kind of graph ?

[image]

I am trying to reproduce only whiskers of a generic boxplot. Vertical lines rapresent a specific range and i would plot points on them in order to highlight which points are inside or outside.
My difficulty is to draw extrema borders of these 1D range lines.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a boxplot ([matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html)). If you just want a line, you can change one the options in the arguments (`widths`). Set it to 0, if you just want a line. One problem is that the caps also change their width to zero. You can fix this by settings the caps `xdata` argument to some value (e.g. -0.1 to 0.1).

You can add data points using plt.scatter().

I hope this helped you.

Code example here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set some random data
data = np.array([20,16,14,1,2,3,4,4.5,7.7,5,6,7,8,9,5,1.1])
x = np.array([1]*len(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create boxplot with 0 widths (just a line)
bp = plt.boxplot(df, widths=0)

# change caps width
for cap in bp['caps']:
    cap.set(xdata=cap.get_xdata() + (-.1,.1))

# get upper and lower cap value
lb = bp['caps'][0].get_ydata()[0]
ub = bp['caps'][1].get_ydata()[0]

# add scatter plot
plt.scatter(x[(data < lb) | (data > ub)], data[(data < lb) | (data > ub)], color='red')
plt.scatter(x[(data>=lb) & (data<= ub)], data[(data>=lb) & (data<= ub)], color='green')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: boxplot]